# Unable to push value into array

Tags: php

There is some stupid mistake with what i am doing, but for some reason i cannot push another key value to an array of arrays...

Here is what i am trying to do:

> ```
> $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Sql Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));  $creatives = array();
>             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>                 $elements[$row["id"]] = array("min_load_size" => $row["min_load_size"], 
>                     "avg_load_size" => $row["avg_load_size"], "max_load_size" => $row["max_load_size"]);
>             }
> ```

After this i am making another call to a differend database and i want to add to each of the arrays another key/value pair. And the code looks like that:

> ```
>     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
>     $arr = $elements[$row["id"]];
>     $arr["technical_attribute_id"] = $row["technical_attribute_id"];
> }
> ```

after that i print out my elements array and there is no "technical_attribute_id" in any of the underlying arrays. there is no doubt that the id's match the keys in the regard.

Thanks

Comment: you are adding that to a new array not the original

Comment: I don't know in what way you push values in an array, generally we use `array_push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use references:

```
$arr = &$elements[$row["id"]];
```

Without the `&` that statement will just make a copy of `$elements[$row['id']]` once it executes the next code line.

Alternatively, you could type the whole thing out:

```
$elements[$row["id"]]["technical_attribute_id"] = $row["technical_attribute_id"];
```

Comment: What's the issue with making a copy of the array.  Doesn't PHP use *copy on write*?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, and it does in that code, because `$arr` is being written to :)